# How to make text-box disable with option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had tried to make text box disable. It's working when I take only single value. When I give or condition like `"1" || "2" || "6"` the text box is not being disabled. And if I select value `"6"` then one text box should exist.

I've tried this code:

```
$('#education').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "6" || "1" || "4") {
        $('#degree').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#degree').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    $('#txtData').show();
    else
        $('#txtData').hide();
});
```

See also the following [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8ZWx/384/).

What shall I change?

Comment: not sure what is requirement... can you please explain more ? Moreover jsfiddle is not appropriate. Please edit

Comment: What is this second `else` for? Your code is wrong !!!

Comment: exaclty and id he has given in js and html he provided are diffrent....

Comment: Second else is - when i select option value 4 then text box should be exist.

Comment: instead of second `else`try to use `($('#txtData').show()).or($('#txtData').hide());` because there is no point in using second `else` if there is no `if`

Comment: @Learning If you want to check for the value `4`, use another `else if(val == "4")` for it, the code won't know it from just an else like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are few errors in the code you wrote, that needs to be fixed:

- To compare a value with three multiple values you can't just call, 
  `$(this).val() == "6" || "1" || "4"` . You need to compare `$(this).val()` with each one of these values separately, or you can put these values in an `array` and check if the value exists.
- You are trying to get an element with ids `degree` and
  `education` that don't exist in the page, make sure to refer existing elements.
- And there's a last `else` mis-placed, when you want to execute
  multiple statements when a condition is `true` just put them all in
  the same `if/else` block.
- If you want to check for a specific value among these 3 values, you can use an inner `if` block inside the first one, to do it.

This is how should be your code:

```
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  if (["6", "1", "4"].indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
    $('#txtData').prop("disabled", true);
    if ("4" == $(this).val())
      $('#txtData').hide();
    else
      $('#txtData').show();
  } else {
    $('#txtData').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#txtData').show();
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  if (["6", "1", "4"].indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
    $('#txtData').prop("disabled", true);
    if ("4" == $(this).val())
      $('#txtData').hide();
    else
      $('#txtData').show();
  } else {
    $('#txtData').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#txtData').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Two</option>
  <option value="5">Three</option>
  <option value="6">Three</option>
</select>
<br /> Input: <input type="text" id="txtData" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable like this: http://jsfiddle.net/a8ZWx/390/

```
$('#education').on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).val() == "6" || $(this).val() == "1" || $(this).val() == "4") {
     $('#txtData').prop("disabled", true);
   } else {
     $('#txtData').prop("disabled", false);
   }
});
```